# What is this "ALB5YD" and "ALBCEA" marked IC does?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit, reverse-engineering

I am trying to reverse engineer this router ups circuit. But one strange thing I noticed, there is 3 IC's are present. But only 2 are needed to maintain the bare bone operation. One of the IC is for charging and protecting the battery, 2nd one is the boost IC. But I can't find any datasheet or any details about the 3rd IC, marked "ALBCEA". But I have found the same circuit but with and different "ALB5YD" marking in this IC. See the photo:
[image]
Another picture but this time the marking is ALBCEA (this is the one I have):
[image]

Comment: high volume users can get custom tolerance IC's where proprietary codes are used for traceability and IP security.  But clearly some form of switch-mode power supply

Comment: You may find 5YD and CEA are date/batch codes. Have you tried searching "ALB SO-8 package"?